# Older version of Collabnet Subversion Edge

Tags: subversion-edge

I want to download older version of Collabnet Subversion Edge. I can't find any site to do it. I want to use 3.x version of it. I know, latest is 4.0.13. It is not need for me. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as it's a request for off-site resources.

Comment: Yes, we should use latest version of Collabnet Subversion Edge. But, sometime we need some stable version which clear bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I got one.

```
  https://downloads-guests.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?collapseFolder=6&folderID=551
```

Yes, we should use latest version of Collabnet Subversion Edge. But, sometime we need some stable version which clear bugs.